# Wix a pushbutton to copy a text into clipboard, use custom action, not working

Tags: c#, wix

I'm learning the Wix to build a installer.

in a custom Dialog, I have a Control, which type is Text, and I have a Button.
I want to click the Button to copy the Text into the Clipboard.

Here are the codes.
First is the Controls.

```
<Control Id="AboutUsInfo" Type="Text" Property="AboutUsText"
                     X="150" Y="20" Width="140" Height="150">
                <Text SourceFile="sample\info2.txt" />
            </Control>
<Control Id="CopyAboutUsButton" Type="PushButton" Text="Copy to the clipboard"
                     X="100" Y="180" Width="80" Height="17">
                <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="CopyAboutUsAction"></Publish>
            </Control>

<Binary Id="Customactions" SourceFile="sample\CustomAction1.CA.dll"></Binary>
```

Here is the CustomAction.

```
    <CustomAction Id="CopyAboutUsAction" BinaryKey="Customactions" DllEntry="CopyToClipboard" Return="ignore">
    </CustomAction>
```

Now the C# code

```
namespace CustomAction1
{
public class CustomActions
{
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CopyToClipboard(Session session)
    {
        session.Log("Begin Copy");
        String s=session["AboutUsText"];
        Clipboard.SetText("this is copy");
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
}
}
```

The Problem is, each time I click the button, my installer says nothing. And nothing happens in my Clipboard.
How can I make this work?

Comment: Most likely it can't find the DLL or can't load it. Run your installation with logging: `msiexec /i package.msi /l*v package.log`. You should see why the installation is aborted in the `package.log` file.

Comment: That's the problem, it says NOTHING! Nothing wrong, Nothing right, just the custom action executed, and return value 1. It doesn't even have a item called "Begin Copy", which is defined in the CustomAction function. The total customaction just doesn't work. I set the return property to ignore, now it doesn't exit because of the error.

Comment: The requirement to copy something to clipboard during the installation process by pushing a button sounds really strange... Have you considered any alternatives? Probably, it's better just using MSI properties for passing data?

Comment: Some users require that .msi installations run in silent mode (without GUI). They would run the .msi file with command line that would set all the required properties. Would your installation work in this case?

Comment: No, I want to show the "About Us" strings, and let the user copy them, and the string are provided as HTML or TXT files. As the scrollabletext Control, it can only read the RTF files, not TXTs. But use Text Control, I cannot do select the Text and ctrl+c. Does anybody have a solution? And my msi will not be run as silent mode.

Comment: @cdytoby Then your custom action process returns 1. You can attach the debugger to the custom action code. Show a Message Box from your custom action to see whether it's called; while the message box is on the screen, attach the debugger to the process and examine what goes wrong.

Comment: @cdytoby If the text is fixed (I guess it's not supposed to be edited by the user), you can simply add what you want to the clipboard in your custom action without communicating to Windows Installer at all.

Comment: You are right! messagebox worked, but clipboard didn't. If I put the messagebox after the clipboard function, the messagebox won't show. That means, clipboard never works. Anybody have an idea why would that happen?

Comment: embed your code in a try catch statement and log the exception into the installer log with a property:
try{
Clipboard.SetText("this is copy");
}catch(Exception ex){
session["ClipboardFailure"] = ex.Message;
session["ClipboardFailure"] = ex.StackTrace;
}

Comment: Thank you! After I add the try and catch, I finally got the Problem: I need to set Thread to STA, so that I can access to the clipboard. but I cannot just add the attribute to the method, I need to start a new Thread. And it worked. Thank you everybody! errrr..... How to mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solved this. I need to start a new thread so that this thread is STA. And it worked. Thank you everyone who added the comments.

```
public class CustomActions
{
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CopyToClipboard(Session session)
    {
        ActionResult ar=ActionResult.Success;
        session.Log("Begin CopyToClipboard");
        //MessageBox.Show("Begin Copy");
        string str="abcde";
        MessageBox.Show(" "+str);
        try
        {
            Thread th=new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ClipboardThread));
            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start(str);
            th.Join();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message+" \n"+ex.StackTrace);
            ar=ActionResult.Failure;
        }
        //MessageBox.Show("End Copy");
        return ar;
    }

    static void ClipboardThread(object s)
    {
        try
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(s.ToString());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message+" \n"+ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```